# How to get Python to run JavaScript on a open chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, python

I've made a python script that grabs IPs you connect to on a website and stores them. I'm checking each time since I don't want to connect to the same IP twice. (This is a bit buggy since I get multiple requests, if someone can explain how to put a timer on the skip call without disrupting the rest of the program).

To auto skip them I'm trying to write a JS script to do so. I think I have the click figured out, but how do I get my python script (local) to tell the javascript to run in the browser? Chrome specifically if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a webdriver for the desired browser and execute javascript code in the browser head and then execute javascript in the browser head from python code much like the auto login commented feature in this application 
https://github.com/engMaher/BAF/blob/master/BAF_0.2.0.py

Comment: Thank you for your help, if I understand a webdriver is used to test your code on multiple browsers. I am a little confused still on how to use this driver to achieve my goal. Do you have any tutorials I can follow? I don't really understand the linked code and it seems like it is used for exploits?

Comment: from the question i get that your goal is to check for connected ips in browser and executes some javascript to prevent connecting to the same ip twice , you can't control browser directly through python code , instead you can create a browser driver and execute the required javascript on demand , if the code snippit in the link ambigious check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SphWVF-OlAY